# Get exactly inserted date_from and date_to

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracleforms, oracle8

I am working in an application in which I need to filter policy by date. For example if user enter `date_from:'21-jul-2017'` and `date_to:'21-jul-2019'` it should display all policies which were created in this period.

So far what I did:

```
cursor o1 is 
 select substr(tarifa,1,2), count(*)
    from   pol p, uvod u, doppov d
    WHERE (izdavanje >=:prebacivanje.od)  AND (izdavanje<=:prebacivanje.do)
    and izdavanje>='01-jul-07'
    and p.orgjed = u.sorgz (+)
    and DATUM_PREKIDA is not null
    and p.polica=d.polica and d.pov_dopl='P'
    and d.status='F'
    and cisti_ao(p.polica)!=0 
    group by substr(tarifa,1,2);
```

`:prebacivanje.od` and `:prebacivanje.do` are `date_from` and `date_to`. Both are DATE fields in the database.

So I need to modify this query to return inserted `date_from` and `date_to` depending of what user entered.

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. What is the problem with the code you've shown? Are the bind variables passed as actual dates, or strings? (I'm not very familiar with Forms! From previous question this if Oracle 8.0.5 and Forms 6.0.5.)

Comment: Look at picture in question. I need to filted date_from and date_to. If user input exact date like : 21-jun-2017  - 21-jul-2019 it need to return all policy in this interval. 
Basically filtering, but I stack in part when I need to redesing this query to take input date in field.

Comment: How can I take exactly date which user inserted in textfield ?

Comment: Isn't that what your query is already doing, by referring to `:prebacivanje.od` and `:prebacivanje.do`?

Comment: Yes, but this query needs to be modify
Since I have no experience enought in PLSQL I have no idea what is the best way to do this.
What I found so far is: to_char(izdavanje,'MM')||to_char(izdavanje,'YY')
Doesnt work for meee ! ! !

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show each year/month in that period and the count of policies in that month, instead of a single count per tariff? If so do you want to see months with no policies, as zero? Sample data and expected results would really help. See [mre].

Comment: Yes, exactly to see all policies year/month in that period and the count of policies in that period
And If it's no policies in this period show as zero (0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a cursor which exists somewhere in a form, that code should probably be executed *somehow*. Is it when you push a button, or what?

Anyway: although you never said what the problem is (do you get an error? If so, which one? ORA-xxxxx, FRM-xxxxx?) (my guess is that query doesn't return anything), it seems that parameters bother you.

Query - as is - is correctly written. Those columns' datatype is `DATE` - that's what items' datatype should be as well. If it is not (but a `CHAR`), you'll have to convert it to `DATE` using `TO_DATE`, e.g.

```
 WHERE izdavanje >= to_date(:prebacivanje.od, 'dd-mon-yy')  
   AND izdavanje <= to_date(:prebacivanje.do, 'dd-mon-yy')
   AND izdavanje >= to_date('01-jul-07'     , 'dd-mon-yy')
```

In order to make sure which format mask to use, display items' values at the beginning of that PL/SQL procedure, using the `MESSAGE` built-in:

```
declare
  cursor o1 is ...
begin
  message('od = ' || :prebacivanje.od);
  message('do = ' || :prebacivanje.do);

  ... the rest of your code goes here
end;
```

Generally speaking, your best option is to make sure that datatypes match; otherwise, you have to take care about conversion or (worse) rely on implicit conversion Oracle will try to perform; sometimes it'll succeed, sometimes not.

Comment: :prebacivanje.od and :prebacivanje.do is DATE field as I see from database.

Comment: @Littlefoot, I like your statement "`sometimes it'll succeed, sometimes not`". I can't tell you how many times I have foolishly thought a number column was stored as a number (it was VARCHAR2) and received the error "unable to convert to number".